# Corned Beef Brisket left out

Tags: food-safety, corned-beef

I purchased a Corned Beef Brisket from the store and forgot to put it in the refrigerator. It was sealed. The package was cool in the morning. Is it safe to still use?

Answer (score -1):

...Ditch It! Why Risk getting Sick and having the "Trots" complete with Chills!